Tryng to install JRE on Ubuntu 24.04 with wine but got error 1627
I've just bought "DeskDockServer" pro app on the Android Store :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.deskdock.free&hl=en
and the server here :
https://www.fdmobileinventions.com/deskdock-server/
I'm trying to configure it now,but unfortunately it does not work. My goal is to be able to share the mouse movements between Android 9.1 installed on my phone (Samsung Note 3) and Ubuntu 24.10.
The developer offers the Android app that should be installed on Android and the server,that can be installed on Mac,on Linux and on Windows.
I tried to establish a connection between the client and the server on Linux and on Windows. The server worked on Windows,but it didn't work on Linux.
I'm interested to use the version for Linux or...the version of Windows emulated with wine on Linux. I tried both the configurations but none worked.
First of all I have configured some options on my mobile phone,such as the accessibility mode and the ADB debug over the wi-fi and then,on Ubuntu 24.04, this is what I did :
ziomario@Z390:/FILES/DeskDockServer_1.3.0# ./adb connect 192.168.1.2:5555

I've got adb here :
https://files.fdmobileinventions.com/DeskDockServer/1.3.0/DeskDockServer_1.3.0.zip
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.1.2:5555       (1.2 is the IP of the phone)

# java -version

openjdk version "21.0.5" 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.5+11-Ubuntu-1ubuntu124.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.5+11-Ubuntu-1ubuntu124.04, mixed mode, sharing)* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.1.2:5555       (192.168.1.2 is the IP of the phone)

and then I tried to install the server part :
ziomario@Z390:/FILES/DeskDockServer_1.3.0# java -jar
DeskDockServer_1.3.0.jar

(The server requires the installation of the Java Runtime Environment 1.7 or newer,that I performed on Ubuntu without problems,installing "OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.5+11-Ubuntu-1ubuntu124.04".
This is what happened as soon as I have launched the java server :
ziomario@Z390:/FILES/DeskDockServer_1.3.0# java -jar
DeskDockServer_1.3.0.jarroot@Z390:/FILES/DeskDockServer_1.3.0

Program: DeskDockServer 1.3.0
System: Linux 6.8.0-48-generic, amd64
JRE: 21.0.5+11-Ubuntu-1ubuntu124.04
class com.floriandraschbacher.deskdockserver.Main: 

Using ADB from /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/DeskDockServer_1.3.0/linux/adb

b@4792b145: Detected device: 192.168.1.2:5555
b@4792b145: Try connect
i@2f796b52: New device: 192.168.1.2:5555
i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket error
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the
trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:132)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:383)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:470)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
       at java.base/
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:586)
       at java.base/
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Abst
ractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
       at java.base/

sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1690)
       at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1614)
       at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLC
onnectionImpl.java:223)
       at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1325)
       at es.a(Unknown Source)
       at eu$b.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors 
parameter must be non-empty
       at java.base/
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:97)
       at java.base/
sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:173)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.ja
va:308)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImp
l.java:183)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.ja
va:198)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerI
mpl.java:132)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCert
s(CertificateMessage.java:1302)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertif
icate(CertificateMessage.java:1195)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(Certifi
cateMessage.java:1138)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:206)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
       ... 9 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the 
trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
       at java.base/
java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
       at java.base/
java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
       at java.base/
java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java
:104)
       at java.base/
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:94)
       ... 25 more

i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket error
i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket error
i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket errorProgram: DeskDockServer 1.3.0
System: Linux 6.8.0-48-generic, amd64
JRE: 21.0.5+11-Ubuntu-1ubuntu124.04
class com.floriandraschbacher.deskdockserver.Main: Using ADB from /home/
ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/DeskDockServer_1.3.0/linux/adb

b@4792b145: Detected device: 192.168.1.2:5555
b@4792b145: Try connect
i@2f796b52: New device: 192.168.1.2:5555
i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket error
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the
trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:132)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:383)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:470)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
       at java.base/
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:586)
       at java.base/
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Abst
ractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
       at java.base/

sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1690)
       at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1614)
       at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLC
onnectionImpl.java:223)
       at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1325)
       at es.a(Unknown Source)
       at eu$b.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors 
parameter must be non-empty
       at java.base/
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:97)
       at java.base/
sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:173)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.ja
va:308)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImp
l.java:183)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.ja
va:198)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerI
mpl.java:132)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCert
s(CertificateMessage.java:1302)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertif
icate(CertificateMessage.java:1195)
       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(Certifi
cateMessage.java:1138)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:206)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
       at java.base/
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
       ... 9 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the 
trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
       at java.base/
java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
       at java.base/
java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
       at java.base/
java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java
:104)
       at java.base/
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:94)
       ... 25 more

i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket error
i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket error
i@2f796b52: Could not connect transporter due to socket error

Since I'm not a programmer,I really don't know how to fix it. For this reason,I tried a different method : I want to install java for Windows on Linux with wine and then,the DeskDockServer for Windows on Linux Ubuntu using wine.
This is what I've been able to achieve :

I have installed wine-gecko-2.47-x86 and x86_64 because it was required by wine and then I ran :
ziomario@Z390:/FILES/DeskDockServer_1.3.0# wine jre-9.0.4_windows-64_bin.exe

As you can see I haven't been able to install JRE for Windows with wine on Ubuntu 24.04. The error that it gives does not give to me enough informations to understand the reasons. Please help me.
